# How to access regex search result inside std::sub_match?

Tags: c++, regex, std

```
std::smatch ipv4Match;
std::regex_match(ipv4, ipv4Match, ip);

if (ipv4Match.empty())
{
    return std::nullopt;
}
else
{
    if (!ipv4Match.empty())
    {
        uint8_t a, b, c, d;
        a = (uint8_t)(ipv4Match[0]);
        b = (uint8_t)(ipv4Match[1]);
        c = (uint8_t)(ipv4Match[2]);
        d = (uint8_t)(ipv4Match[3]);
   }
}
```

However it obviously not work. I've researched and when I access `smatch` using `[]`, it returns a [sub_match](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match), which does not have public members unless the constructor.

How can I convert each part of the match of the ip address into a byte?

Most importantly, how can `std::cout << ipv4Match[0]` work if it cannot access the inner string inside the `ipv4Match` since it's a `sub_match`?

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov I left the second if because I'll add ipv6 support later also. So, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/operator_at returns ` std::sub_match`

Comment: The `std::sub_match` has `length`, `str`, `operator string_type`, and `compare` public methods. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/sub_match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is unrelated to regex, but string to int conversion.

You might use `std::atoi`/`std::stoi`:

```
uint8_t a = std::stoi(ipv4Match[1].str());
uint8_t b = std::stoi(ipv4Match[2].str());
uint8_t c = std::stoi(ipv4Match[3].str());
uint8_t d = std::stoi(ipv4Match[4].str());
```